# Iterate with Ruby through git commits for a particular branch

Tags: git, libgit2, rugged

I'd like to use Rugged to iterate through all the commits on a particular branch, from the oldest (first) to the newest (last). I'd like to examine the SHA1 and the comment for each.

Maybe I'm better off just running 'git log --reverse' and parsing the results, but as long as there's this nice Ruby library for working with Git I figure I'll use it.

Forgive me but I can't quite figure out how to do what I want from the Rugged or libgit2 docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a commit walker, something like this:

```rb
require 'rugged'

repo = Rugged::Repository.new('/path/for/your/repo')
walker = Rugged::Walker.new(repo)
walker.sorting(Rugged::SORT_REVERSE)
walker.push(repo.branches["master"].target_id)

walker.each do |commit| 
  puts "commit #{commit.oid}"
  puts "Author: #{commit.author[:name]} <#{commit.author[:email]}>"
  puts "Date:   #{commit.author[:time]}"
  puts "\n    #{commit.message}\n"
end
walker.reset
```

You can check the [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rugged/Rugged) and read the [testing code](https://github.com/libgit2/rugged/tree/master/test) in the repository to see what you can do with Rugged.

Comment: Thanks @hector. Eventually I figured it out, doing almost the same  as what you wrote, but I used SORT_DATE and reversed the whole thing. Maybe yours is a bit better.